# Prove by induction that for all n the division of a(n) by 8 will have a remainder of 1.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

Define the sequence $a(n)$ for all $n \in\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4...\}$ by $a(n)= 2 \cdot 5^n + 7$
Show by induction that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ the rest of the division of $a(n)$ by $8$ is always $1$.

I started doing the problem but I'm very stuck and I feel like I made a mistake at some point? Although it seems like it would lead to the answer. This is how I approached the problem:
Basis step: $a(0) = 2 \cdot 5^0 + 7 = 9$ and   $9 \pmod{1} \equiv 1$ so it has a remainder of 1.

Inductive hypothesis: Assume that $a(k) = 2 \cdot 5^k + 7$ has a remainder of 1 when divided by 8.

Must show: $a(k+1) = 2 * 5^{(k+1)} + 7 $ has a remainder of $1$ when divided by 8
We have:
\begin{align}
a(k) &= 2 \cdot 5^k + 7 \\
&= 8m + 1 
\end{align}
(this is to show that a(k) is an integer multiplied by 8 and +1 to show there is a remainder of 1)

$
2 \cdot 5^k + 7 = 8m + 1
$
We are going to isolate $5^k$:

$$
5^k = (8m + 1 - 7)/2
$$
so
$$
5^k = (8m-6)/2
$$
Now we do the side with k+1
\begin{align}
a(k+1)
&= 2 \cdot  5^{(k+1)} + 7\\
&= 2 \cdot 5^k \cdot 5^1 + 7
\end{align}
We can plug in the $5^k$ we found from earlier.
\begin{align}
&= 2 \left(\frac{8m-6}{2}\cdot  5\right) + 7\\
&= 10(8m-6) + 7\\
&= 80m - 60 + 7\\
&= 80m - 53\\
&= 8(10m) - 53
\end{align}
However this doesn't actually show that there would be a remainder of 1 when I divide by 8.
I'm not sure where I went wrong in the steps.
I wasn't sure how to include subscripts and superscripts so I'm sorry in advance for that!

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  And if $8$ divides $2\times5^n+6$, then $8$ divides $5(2\times5^n+6)-24=2\times5^{n+1}+6$

Comment: Please check your arithmetic again. I believe there is an error in the lines after "we can plug in the 5k we found from earlier".

Comment: Thank you for the mathJax tutorial! Very helpful for formatting. I am not sure where the +6 is coming from in your response. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @CalvinLin I double checked and I am not seeing the error

Comment: The remainder when $2\times5^n+7$ is divided by $8$ is $1$, if, and only if, $2\times5^n+6$ is divisible by $8$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Right, makes sense. I will try to use that and show it using induction in my response.

Comment: What is $ 2( 1/2(8m-6)5)$ equal to? Is it $10(8m-6)$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh you're right it should be a 5 instead of a 10

Comment: Can you go through and fix the error and subsequent statements, then see if it works out?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, in fact it does, it leads me to the same answer as the person who answered the post down below! Thank you for showing me my error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement is equivalent to :

Prove that, $2\cdot 5^n+6\equiv 0\pmod 8$ or $5^n+3\equiv 0\pmod 4$ using induction .

Without using induction, you can observe that :

$$
\begin{align}5^n+3&\equiv5^n-1\\
&\equiv 5^n-1^n \\
&\equiv 0\pmod 4 \end{align}
$$

That is correct, since :

$$5^n-1^n=(5-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}5^k$$

However, it is also possible to solve the original problem by induction .

---

Define $a_n=2\cdot 5^n+7$, then :

For $n\in\{0,1\}$ the statement is trivially correct .

Assuming that, for $n=k$ the statement is also correct for some $m\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ .

$$a_k=2\cdot 5^k+7=8m+1$$

Then for $k+1$, you have :

$$
\begin{align}a_{k+1}&=2\cdot 5^{k+1}+7\\
&=5\left(a_k-7\right)+7\\
&=5\left(8m+1-7\right)+7\\
&=40m-23\\
&=8\left(5m-3\right)+1\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Thus, by induction you are done .

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems like I made a mistake when multiplying earlier which made me have a slightly different answer

Comment: @Esravei My phone's screen is broken, therefore I couldn't check your formulas. I could only read your sentences.  I am sorry for that .

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I fixed, Thank you very much .